# List of all Stack Overflow link shortcuts

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

When commenting on questions/answers it's possible to type

`[Ask]` to link to `https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask`

and

`[mcve]` to link to `https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve`

Is there a resource anywhere which lists all possible shortcuts?

Comment: Yes: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting